# Get list of orders without a tracking number

Tags: magento2, orders, shipment

I am new at Magento and I would like to get a list of orders/sales without a tracking number/shipment using the REST API. I was looking at the documentation https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger but I could not find anything.

Is there any endpoint I can use?

Since I could not find that, I was thinking of getting all orders and then checking if a shipment exists for it, but that is not really efficient as there are a lot of orders.

Thank you

Comment: this might help you a lot https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/performing-searches.html

Comment: @PhilippSander Where can I get a list of all the fields that can be used in the searchscriteria?

Comment: this always depends on the entity